# cron inside docker not running jobs on linux host (but running jobs on mac host)

Tags: docker, cron

I have a test docker container with cron running in the foreground. The cron should say "hello" every minute. But it does not. It works on my Mac but it doesn't work on my server (Ubuntu 18.04.1). It just hangs and does nothing like if there wasn't any cron scheduled.

this is my Dockerfile (./crond/Dockerfile):

```
FROM alpine:3.10
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk add --no-cache docker
RUN apk add --no-cache docker-compose
```

this is my docker-compose.yml (./):

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  cron:
    image: crond
    build:
      context: ./crond
    entrypoint: /docker-container-entrypoint
    volumes:
      - ./crontab:/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
      - ./crond/entrypoint:/docker-container-entrypoint
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

this is the entrypoint (./crond/entrypoint)

```
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash crond -l 8 -f
```

this is the crontab file (./crontab):

```
*  *  *  *  * echo "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should use [docker dind image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) instead of using alpine and then install the docker, docker dind is also based on alpine.

```
FROM docker:dind

ADD crontab /etc/crontabs/root 

CMD ["crond", "-f"]
```

output

```
crond[1]: crond (busybox 1.30.1) started, log level 8
crond[1]: USER root pid  14 cmd echo hello world from cron
hello world from cron
```

Also you do not need the entrypoint, CMD can work or change it to

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "starting cron job container"
exec "$@"
```

And the path for cron mounting is `/etc/crontabs/`

Answer (score -1):

I found the similar problem, but if I quit mounting the cron config file, (`./crontab:/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` in your case), and make a Dockerfile to `COPY` the config to the same place, it works,

```
FROM some-image

COPY crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
CMD crond -f
```